# How data goes to a specific sheet based on combobox entry

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I'm working on a simple VB form I created on my excel worksheet. I'm trying to code that data form entry will go to a specific sheet based on the combobox entry.

Example:

I got combobox with different names. When name "Albert" is selected, all data entry on that form will go to Albert Worksheet.

Comment: You might also want to include the procedures you tried in your post.

Comment: Havent done any procedures. Im basically new to this. I dont know how will i code it. I just have a simple code that copies entry from form to worksheet

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of option buttons, for example, you could set it up so that when you click the option is sets the destination workbook and then make reference to that when you submit the data from the form.

```
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet

Private Sub optAlbert_Change()
  Set wsDestination = Worksheet("Albert")
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
  wsDestination.Range("A1").Value = txtSomething.Value
End Sub
```

I am not sure of your enumeration details but you would just have to change the values as required including adding more info needed.
You could also use the combobox selection to either lookup/iteration through a list/array and then set the destination as well.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
  Select Case cboDestSheet.Value
    Case 1
      strDest = "Albert"
    Case 2
      strDest = "Tim"
  End Select
  Set wsDestination = Worksheets(strDest)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is only possible using options buttons? I used combobox to enumerate my options.

Comment: Just use whatever your control is to drive the worksheet.
So maybe a case function in the combo and read it when the form is submitted.

Comment: Can you post a sample code sir so i would have an idea on how to start?

Comment: I cant seem to have this work.


Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Select Case cboName.Value
    Case 1
      strDest = "Animals"
    Case 2
      strDest = "Things"
    Case 3
      strDest = "Solar"
    Case 4
      strDest = "Sea"
    End Select

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Animals")
Set ws = Worksheets("Things")
Set ws = Worksheets("Solar")
Set ws = Worksheets("Sea")

Comment: You need to set the worksheet to the variable strDest which will contain the string value based on your combo box selection like I have in the code.